# Have screen rotation option always on

Tags: auto-rotation

The screen rotation of my phone works fine. When I rotate the phone from portrait to landscape, then a small icon appears in the lower right corner. I have to click it, then the screen rotates. Going back from landscape to portrait works similarly.

Is it possible to have this icon in the lower right corner at all times? I.e., allowing me to rotate the screen at any time (by tapping the icon), but suppressing auto-rotation after I physically rotate the device?

In the options of my phone, I do not find that possibility. (See screenshot.) I also searched the internet, but what I could find was more concerned with bugs of the screen rotation (which I do not experience).

[image: Screenshot of Settings -> Display -> Navigation bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This answer assumed the device in question is Samsung based on its screenshot.*

---

On Samsung devices, it is possible to show an always-on screen rotation button with the help of **the Assistant menu**.

1. Open Settings - Accessibility - Interaction and dexterity
2. Tap "Assistant menu"
3. Tap "Select Assistant menu items"
4. Add "Screen rotation" (and optionally remove the rest)
5. Switch "On" the feature
6. (Optionally, configure the size and its transparency)

The Assistant menu can also be moved around by holding and dragging the button.

[image]

Comment: My phone is indeed a Samsung device. And thanks for your suggestion, this works. For me, it would be even better if the symbol was part of the navigation bar at the bottom end of the screen. But I will try this for a while now.

Comment: @NerdOnTour unfortunately, unless the manufacturer allows navigation bar customization (to some degree), further customization is usually impossible without a rooted device/custom ROM because it's integrated into the system's UI framework.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't appear there's a way to do this directly in the Android system. For most phones the standard options are:

1. Auto-Rotate ON: Your phone rotates automatically when you adjust its rotation
2. Auto-Rotate OFF Your phone doesn't rotate automatically but gives a small button to allow for rotation (Android 12 and up)

Although there is no way to do it within the Android system settings, there is an app called [Always Visible Screen Rotation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alwaysrotate&hl=en_US&gl=US) that looks like it does exactly the thing you're looking for. It places a small icon on the screen that can be activated whether your device is physically rotated or not.

[image: Always Visible Screen Rotation Screenshot]

Comment: Am I right that this is more or less Andrew T's answer, but it works also for non-Samsung devices?

Comment: @NerdOnTour based on my knowledge, yes. Unless the manufacturer added such a feature, the usual alternative/general solution is to use 3rd-party apps as a replacement. For instance, the Accessibility menu (Assistant menu on Samsung) on Pixel devices cannot be customized and doesn't have a screen rotation button, thus it needs a 3rd-party installation.